# How to measure improvement in Mental Acuity/Sharpness?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, measurement, experimental-psychology, brain-training

Are there any accurate tools that can tell the changes in mental acuity/sharpness?

Comment: I edited the question to remove reference to self-help. CogSci discourages self-help and we advice you to seek professional help. This is a scientific questions-and-answers forum, nothing more (and nothing less :-)